# check if solution to sin(x)=5 is real

Tags: syntax, sage

I tried this and it returns "True"

```
a = solve(sin(x)==5, x); print(a[0].rhs() in RR)
```

However the expected answer is "False", what am I missing?

I just want to programmatically check when I have real solutions to some equations.

I also tried `len(a)` which returns '1' which is also not correct as there are infinite many [non-real] solutions.

I also tried `a = solve(sin(x)==1, x) print(a[0].rhs()<pi)`

which return neither true nor false but the string "pi/2 < pi "

Comment: Downvoter, you probably should have explained your vote, though I agree the first question may not be a programming question.  However, the second question definitely is, and I have answered it (I hope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly because

```
sage: n(arcsin(5))
NaN
```

though perhaps that shouldn't really be in `RR` either.  Interestingly, `NaN` is not in `ZZ`.

As to your other question,

```
sage: a = solve(sin(x)==1, x); print(bool(a[0].rhs()<pi))
```

should work better.  Sage keeps symbolic (in)equalities that way as long as possible without evaluation, usually.

Answer (score 1):

Let's back up a bit.

There are an infinite number of solutions to sin(x)==5.
They can be represent by the set
q*(-1)^n +n*pi
 for integer n, and where q is a principal arcsin of 5,
for example 
approximately q = 1.5707963267948966192 - 2.2924316695611776878 * i

So what's the problem??  We can observie that none of the solutions is real, 
but perhaps Sage is unable to make that observation.

And the numeric value of arcsin(5) should probably
not be NaN, because it certainly is a number, just not a real number.
Unless Sage's arcsin doesn't know about complex numbers.

Comment: thx @Richard I understand there are infinite many solutions, but I want to know how to ask Sage to count the number of Real solutions for the moment i am using "bool(a[0].rhs()<pi)" as suggested above which is working ok as it returns true when the solution is real and false when not real.. but seems not elegant..